# Combos enlazados

Tags: combobox

tengo dos combos dependientes, uno de especies y el otro de variedades. Estoy intentando que al seleccionar una especie del combo de especies, se me rellene el combo de variedades con las variedades de esa misma especie, Mi código sería este.

```
Script:
    $(function() {
        $("#esp.nombre").select({
            source: "variedadesEspecie",
            minLength: 3,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                this.value = ui.item.label;
                $("#esp.nombre__input").val(ui.item.value2);
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

Y por último, controlador:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/variedadesEspecie")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<LabelValueDTO> variedadesEspecie(
            @RequestParam(value = "term", required = false, defaultValue = "") String term) {
        List<LabelValueDTO> suggestions = new ArrayList<LabelValueDTO>();

        try {
//          variedades = variedadService.listarEspeciesPorId(term);
            for (Variedad variedad : variedades) {
                LabelValueDTO lv = new LabelValueDTO();
                lv.setValue(variedad.getIdEspecie().getId());
                lv.setValue2(variedad.getId());
                lv.setLabel2(variedad.getNombre());
                suggestions.add(lv);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.error("Exception en obtencion de variedades de la especie", e);
        }

        return suggestions;
    }
```

Cuando hago la selección de una especie, teniendo un punto de ruptura en el controlador, al seleccionar la misma especie, este no llega ni a entrar en el controlador ni dar ningún tipo de error ni nada ¿Cómo podría entonces enlazar dichos combos?

Comment: Buenas, está bien especificar que tecnologías estás utilizando en los tags. En este caso parece una página html con JQuery y una api con Spring. Sin embargo, por ejemplo, no queda claro la forma de comunicación de tu front con el servidor ya que en el código mostrado en ningún momento haces una petición al método del servidor para que te devuelva los datos.

Comment: La parte frontal se comunica con la parte de negocio de esta manera source: "variedadesEspecie", la cual "variedadesEspecie" se comunica con el controlador de esta manera "@RequestMapping(value = "/variedadesEspecie")". Pero al ejecutar en modo de depuración no entra de ninguna manera al controlador, ni da ningún tipo de error ni en el html ni en la parte java, al arrancar, todo bien, pero al ejecutar, ni si quiera llega a entrar en el controlador de la parte java. Me faltaba añadir los dos combos, pero no puedo añadirlos de ninguna manera, ya que el editor me pone trabas

Comment: Y donde estas llamando al controlador? que lenguaje o framework usas en el front? y en el back? yo no veo ninguna llamada de tipo ajax ni de ningun otro tipo...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y por favor, usa el boton [edit] y aclara todos los problemas en la pregunta....

Comment: Lo llamo aquí en "source: "variedadesEspecie",", que está en el código jQuery del html. Los lenguajes que uso son html, thymeleaf, jQuery y java, y el framework que utilizo es Spring Boot

Comment: SAlvo que estes usando un framework que desconozco, eso no hace una llamada api... pero mejor se lo dejo a alguien que se conozca. Igual si no modificas las etiquetas de tu pregunta con la informacion correcta, nadie se va a enterar....

Comment: Yo tampoco he visto nada parecido nunca y he trabajado en ese stack, vamos a ver si lo encaminamos. El método select de JQuery (https://api.jquery.com/select/) espera de parámetro una función, le estás pasando un objeto. Esa función debería hacer la llamada ajax a tu ruta de la api con por ejemplo fetch (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).  En la parte de spring indica a tu controlador que el método será GET en el @RequestMapping(value="/variedadesEspecie", method=RequestMethod.GET).